# MS Access manual Auto incrementing field

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

Im building a system for my company to keep track of internal orders, inbetween our warehouses, we have material that goes out warehouse 1 to warehouse 2 and we kind of lose track of how much of "x" is in warehouse 1 and how much in warehouse 2, so i want to implement this access db where a user fills a form and says: order 1: 500 of "x" order 2: 300 of "y". then another user fills an exit form where he says 1 of "x" going out, so i would need the program to keep track of total order and how much as gone out to fill order 1 and so on...

My idea here is to have both an order number and an id number for each of "x" everytime someoneone assembles 1 "x" they fill the form and print a label directly from the access (i have this part working already) while keeping a record of when it was assembled, who verified and what was verified (it will work as a quality control also).

What i dont know is how to program the db so when it reaches 500 of "x", the id number for "x" starts again from 1

This is the one major issue with my program right now, i'm not experienced in access db's or vba, but im getting there with a tip and a trick from here and there, so, no need to be careful with the technical language, i will google it if i have to :p

EDIT:

The table structure goes as follows:

1 table as the main table where I record the check that is made for every product, where I include the model of the product, the said ID that I want to reset after a number of products checked, and a concatenated field that includes most of this information to generate a qr code.

Then there is a table for the Order Number, which is connected to a form to record each new order with a date/time field, the order number itself and the number of products. This number of products must then be called from the code that will count how many products have been checked to date and keep the order number field updated so we can keep track of the order.

Then there is another minor table just to get values for the form, the product models

Thank you for your answers ;)

Comment: Please edit this question to remove the "other minor issues" and ask each one as a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Questions on Stack Overflow should be about a single specific issue.

Comment: Is it worth keeping an inventory? That would allow you to not only count the current items in each location, but also see exactly which are where.

Answer (score 1):

[See this MSDN Documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718)

Unfortunately in Access, you cannot 'reset' an ID field, unless you move the records to a newly created table and use that table for every 500 records.

As for the user control and login form, I'm afraid those are separate questions that must be asked in a different thread.

To get you started:

You can set the `RecordSource` of a form to a table, and when users make entries, the data will be saved to the table. You can also use a form with controls (text boxes, comboboxes, etc.) and create a button that runs a query to insert these records into a table.

The login piece - you can encrypt the database with a password. That may/may not be sufficient.

Comment: that is a good answer with some good ideas, but the idea is not to reset an id field, i called it id, i could've called it potatoe, it just means the field must count up to 500, or whatever number the order is and then start from 1, it wont even the the key field, so no problem for duplicate entries or anything like that, it must be a  number field, a regular number field, but instead of being filled manually, ideally it would be filled automatically increasing 1 for every record, thats basically what i want. About the login, yeah, i will create another question, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This also raises a couple other questions. Can you update your question with a table schema that you are imagining. I would better be able to help think through your problem with more supporting information about what you're thinking of doing. Sorry for the confusion, also

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you change your schema, if possible.  Something like the following:

**Orders**

- *OrderID*  (Autonumber)
- *ProductID*  (link to your Products table)
- *QuantityRequested*

**Deliverables**

- *DeliverableID* (Autonumber)
- *OrderID* (link to your Orders table)
- *SequenceNumber*: in the BeforeInsert event set this value equal to:

---

```
DCount("*", "Deliverables", "OrderID=" & Me.OrderID) + 1
```

---

I'm assuming that your form has a control named `OrderID` that is bound to the OrderID field of the Deliverables table.

The code uses the `DCount()` function to get the count of all the other deliverables that have already been created for this order.  If this is the first deliverable, `DCount()` will return 0.  It then adds 1 to this count to get the sequence number of the next deliverable.

If the new SequenceNumber is greater than the quantity requested, you could display a message saying that the order has been filled and cancel the creation of the Deliverable record.

This is just one approach and it is not a complete solution.  I'm assuming that once assigned a sequence number a deliverable cannot be deleted.  You might need to make allowances for deliverables that get lost or damaged.  You could incorporate a status field to the Deliverable table to deal with this, but you would still need to make a decision about what to do with the SequenceNumber.

Comment: Although I dont seems to understand your answer very well, I got an idea from it. I could create a new table for every order (either through a form or manually because really there are not a lot of orders, and they take quite a while to fulfill) and get the DCount ( expression, domain, [criteria] ) +1 function to count records in the new table until they reach the order value. After that, i know what to do. I will mark them as an extra because often we do more than the order in case the one that made the order, decides the initial value is not enough

Comment: Please don't create a new table for every order...you will be creating a maintenance nightmare for yourself or someone else down the road.  I would suggest you do some quick research on "database normalization."

Comment: the thing is, this seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution, with a new table for every order, i could use the autonumber on every order  and it wouldnt be that messy cause we get a new order like every 2 months, so, with around 6 new tables per year, i think it would be messy only in about 10 years... Inbetween i can work on a better version of the database